How to include cxxopts.hpp in clion
I'm not fluent in C++/cmake and I'm trying to figure out how to use conan package management in Jetbrains CLion.  I was able to get a json library working but while I can manage to install cxxopts, the IDE can't seem to find it and doesn't include the conan directory install of cxxopts in the 'External libraries'
I though the thing that would do it is adding the cxxopts_INCLUDE_DIRS to include_directories in CMakeLists.txt like I did with the nlohman_json_INCLUDE_DIRS.  But while the program compiles, jetbrains is still marking problems and saying it can't find cxxopts.hpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(lurning)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

find_package(nlohmann_json REQUIRED)
find_package(cxxopts REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    ${nlohmann_json_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${cxxopts_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(
    lurning
    main.cpp
    Lurning.h
)

target_link_libraries(
    lurning
    PRIVATE
    ${cxxopts_LIBRARIES}
)

Can anyone help me figure out what is missing so I can make sure CLion finds the file?

Figures, right after posting I realized I hadn't told CLion to rebuild from the CMakeLists.txt - once I did that, the directory showed up in Header Search Paths and the in-IDE errors went away.  sigh
Lurning kervs!
